# Is it possible to remove the battery percentage on my Samsung S5?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have a Galaxy S5 running 4.4.2, unrooted.

In the top indicator bar, there is an icon of a battery, and a percentage of remaining battery life beside it (not inside of it, as I've seen other people mention).

I find the percentage being there kind of stresses me out. I look at it and wonder if the drop from 90% to 80% over the last little while is indicative of lots of battery use, and whether or not my phone will last the day.

Can I get rid of it? I'm okay with just a battery icon.

Ideally, a percentage would only show once I'm under a critical point, like 20% or so.

Here is what my battery settings look like:

[image]
[image]

<sup>Click image(s) for larger versions</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Android 5.0, and now the option to hide battery percentage is available with a simple checkbox in the battery settings interface.

Answer (score 1):

Battery percentage is used by users to charge the device based on the percentage(if the charge <25 % then charge the device till 100% and if not less then 25 % then do not charge in order to extend your battery life)

The below steps are common for all the Android devices with version greater then Android 4.1(jelly bean) to the present Android 4.4 (KitKat) only with some minor modifications.

You can simply uncheck the Show Battery Percentage in the Settings.

Go  to the settings>Battery.

[image: Step 1 Settings>Battery]

In that you can see that the Show battery Percentage is checked. You can simply uncheck that and the battery percentage will not be displayed.

[image: Step 2 Battery>Uncheck the show battery percentage]

If at all the check box is not under the battery menu then you might be having it under the Display menu.

Last but not the least please check if your device is available for the Update to Android 4.4.4 if yes then go ahead with the update.

Comment: Thank you for this response. However, in Android 4.4.2 on a Samsung Galaxy S5, there is no checkbox in the location you've indicated. The screenshots look like maybe they're from an earlier version of Android perhaps.

Comment: @DaveMG check the updated screen shots. Moreover the above steps are common in devices running with Android 4.1 and above.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, I swear my Samsung does not have the "Show battery percentage" checkbox anywhere in the battery settings. It looks exactly like your second image with the graph and the list of applications, but no checkbox for battery percentage.

Comment: @DaveMG then could you please attach the screen shot of the settings menu as well as the battery menu to get a clear view of the problem(press the power/lock and the home button together for few seconds and the screen shot will be captured to your phone memmory) .Also add the software version of your phone from about phone.

Comment: I've added screenshots to the question. Also, I've already stated the Android version is 4.4.2. I'm not sure what other software version you might be referring to.

Comment: @DaveMG check my update and I was referring to the Settings>About device .In about device menu you can see the exact Android version installed on your device (to make sure you are giving the correct Software about your device and is helpful for some people as some manufacturers specify another Android version in the specs and install a different Android version on the device)

Comment: The exact Android version is 4.4.2, as stated. There is no other software version information that I can see. I checked for updates, but none were available.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings>>>battery>>>scroll down and uncheck the "Display Battery Percentage" option.

Comment: Thank you for this response. However, in Android 4.4.2 on a Samsung Galaxy S5, there is no checkbox in the location you've described.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the screenshot above try at the bottom of the list of apps under battery, if not try under settings > display and might be there somewhere

Comment: Thanks for this response. There is no percentage option in either of these locations.

Comment: The only other option I can think of for you is to root your phone and then install Wanam Xposed from the google play store, when you open the app it will prompt you to install the Xposed Firmware so go ahead and do that, back then to Wanam you'll be able to do many customizations to your notification/status bar including remove the percentage from battery

Comment: @DaveMG Are you sure? On a 4.4.2 Galaxy S4, it's definitely in **Display** settings (if you have tab view, **Display** is on the **My device** tab). Did you scroll down? It's not visible when you first open the **Display** settings page. You have to scroll way down, it's one of the last settings. Not very intuitive; it really should be in **Battery** settings (or in both locations, if they must have it under **Display**).

Comment: @AdiInbar, on my device, under the `Display` section, the bottommost item is `Increase touch sensitivity`. There is no check box for showing the percentage. I have looked in every location suggested in every answer and comment, and the option does not exist on my phone in any of the locations suggested so far.

Comment: @DaveMG For the record, I didn't say "bottommost", I said "one of the last". It *should* be the third item above **Increase touch sensitivity**. But actually I just noticed that I *do* have it in both places. There's also a checkbox scrolled off the bottom in the **Battery** settings. Odd that you wouldn't have it in either place; documentation for the S5 indicates that this hasn't changed. Are you using a custom ROM? I notice that you have a different them (no cogwheel, different organization). If you bought it used it's possible that you might have a custom ROM without even knowing it...

Comment: @AdiInbar, I don't have a rooted or custom ROM that I know of, but it is possible that my carrier (DoCoMo) modified it in some way.

Answer (score 1):

This was a boggle for me as well, but I found it if click on battery, then the display at the top and then display at the bottom once more and finally about half way down you have display battery percentage.

Comment: Thank you for this response, but your description is not clear. What do you mean by "then the display at the top and then display at the bottom once more"?

Answer (score 1):

I was losing hope of finding this on my Sony Xperia Z2 Tablet which runs Android 4.4.4, but finally I did. On my device it's under Settings -> Device -> Personalisation -> Status bar icons. 
Hope this helps you find it on your Samsung device as well.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Unfortunately, under settings, I don't have a `Device`, `Personalization`, or `Status bar icons` screens anywhere that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using android 4.4.4 goto Settings>Battery, then up the top right hand side click on the battery icon. This should bring a drop down menu to change the battery symbol.